# Use .MDF file in c#

Tags: c#, sql-server, desktop-application

I have an `.mdf` file. I want to use it in c# in desktop application.

This is my connection string :

```
string cwd = System.IO.Directory.GetCurrentDirectory();
string ConString = @"Data Source=.\SQLEXPRESS; AttachDbFilename=" + cwd + "\\SalaryProgram.mdf;Integrated Security=True;User Instance=True";
```

How can I use the `.mdf` file in C# ?

I am getting this error :

> An attempt to attach an auto-named database for file D:\Naresh Backup\SalaryProgram\Latest Work\SalaryProgram\SalaryProgram\bin\Debug\SalaryProgram.mdf failed. A database with the same name exists, or specified file cannot be opened, or it is located on UNC share.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: The message seems pretty clear: a database **of that same name** already exists - you cannot have two databases of the same name in your SQL Server Express instance...

Comment: I haven't DB with same name on my local pc. Previously, i used DB from another pc(Shared), now i want to use that mdf file  in my local.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check the following 3 things:

1. Make sure your MDF file was created by the same or older version of SQL Server than the one installed on the target machine.
2. Make sure that the SQL Server on target machine doesn't already have a database with the same name.
3. Always prefer `Path.Combine()` over direct concatenation of folder path and file name. Sometimes a function returns ending backslash character as part of the path, other times it doesn't. So direct concatenation can result in illegal paths.
4. You may want to look into the [|DataDirectory|](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/smartclientdata/archive/2005/08/26/456886.aspx) feature too, intsead of `GetCurrentDirectory()`.

Comment: So, i have to put my mdf file in this folder : C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL10.SQLEXPRESS\MSSQL\DATA ?
Or can i put it in project folder ?

Comment: You can put it anywhere you want. The DataDirectory macro can be configured programmatically to point to any folder you want. The link I provided above has more info on that.

Comment: string ConString = @"Data Source=.\SQLEXPRESS; AttachDbFilename=|DataDirectory|\SalaryProgram.mdf;Integrated Security=True;User Instance=True";
This is my connection string now. 
I got the following error : An attempt to attach an auto-named database for file D:\Naresh Backup\SalaryProgram\Latest Work\SalaryProgram\SalaryProgram\bin\Debug\SalaryProgram.mdf failed. A database with the same name exists, or specified file cannot be opened, or it is located on UNC share.

Comment: I haven't such database on my local pc, it is on another (shared) pc.

Comment: Try attaching it manually in SQL Server Management Studio against the same SQL Server instance and see if this particular db file works.

Comment: while attaching on local SQLEXPRESS : TITLE: Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio. Attach database failed for Server DOTNET1\SQLEXPRESS'.  (Microsoft.SqlServer.Smo)ADDITIONAL INFORMATION:An exception occurred while executing a Transact-SQL statement or batch. (Microsoft.SqlServer.ConnectionInfo)
Unable to open the physical file "D:\Naresh Backup\SalaryProgram\Database\09-04-2013\SalaryProgram.mdf". Operating system error 5: "5(Access is denied.)". (Microsoft SQL Server, Error: 5120)

Comment: Yes, you can work with the DB without permanently attaching it. I was just checking if the file itself is valid. But after seeing the error msg your posted above, it looks like you either have permissions problem in the specified folder, or the file itself is in use by some other software.

Comment: Ok, and one another question : To Use mdf file without attaching , it is necessary that the SQLEXPRESS must have to install on my local PC ?

Comment: Yes. But you have other options too. E.g. you can use SQLite which can be deployed freely along with your application and doesn't require installation as such. Also, .NET has built-in support for SQLCE, which is easy to deploy.

Comment: Ohhh. I think , that is the problem with Sql version. The created mdf file with sql server 10.0.1600 and my local pc version is 10.0.5500.

Comment: and, if i haven't install SQLEXPRESS on pc , should i remove "Data Source=.\SQLEXPRESS;" in my connection string (@"Data Source=.\SQLEXPRESS; AttachDbFilename=|DataDirectory|\SalaryProgram.mdf;Integrated Security=True;User Instance=True")

Comment: That was what I told you first thing in my answer; check the SQL Server version. Happy you figured it out. About the `Data Source` part of the connection string, that is a must in case of SQL Server (both full and Express) and tells ADO.NET about the server name. In case of SQLCE and SQLite, it may not be required. (plz check this last statement for accuracy, i m just recalling from the back of my brain).

Comment: ok, As you told me , it is not necessary to install SQLEXPORESS on pc to use mdf file, i stop SQLEXPRESS service on my local pc and also all the sql service on my shared pc. Now i run the program , getting error : A network-related or instance-specific error occurred while establishing a connection to SQL Server. The server was not found or was not accessible. Verify that the instance name is correct and that SQL Server is configured to allow remote connections. (provider: SQL Network Interfaces, error: 26 - Error Locating Server/Instance Specified)

Comment: Read my answers again. I said it IS necessary to have SQLEXPRESS installed and running to attach your db.

Answer (score 0):

In one of my previous project (winform application in C#), I was using a DB say "EmployeeMaster".

Connection string that worked for me was:

"Data Source=(local)\SQLExpress;Initial Catalog=EmployeeMaster;Trusted_Connection=Yes;"

Give it a try.

Comment: ok. but, i don't want to create DB in my local pc. i just want to use existing mdf file. is it possible ?

Answer (score 0):

I’d really recommend that you attach this MDF file to your local instance regularly and then connect to database. Attaching mdf files in asp.net applications is not really the best way to go with this.

Just add connection string to your aplication config file

```
<connectionStrings>
            <add name="yourConnectionString" connectionString=
"Data Source=(local); Initial Catalog=database_name;Integrated Security=True"     
 providerName="System.Data.SqlClient"/>
    </connectionStrings>
```

Then use it in your code like this:

```
string ConString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["yourConnectionString 
"].ConnectionString
```